# Entries of ElasticSearch hits

Tags: elasticsearch

I am performing an ElasticSearch query through

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_search?pretty' -d '{\"_source\":[\"data.js_event\", \"data.timestamp\",\"data.uid\",\"data.element\"],\"query\":{\"match\":{\"event\":\"first_time_user_event\"}}}'
```

I am ONLY interested in the ouput of `_source` but the retrieval leads to something like

```
{"took" : 46,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 71,
    "successful" : 71,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 2062326,
    "max_score" : 4.8918204,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "logstash-2015.11.22",
      "_type" : "fluentd",
      "_id" : "AVEv_blDT1yShMIEDDmv",
      "_score" : 4.8918204,
      "_source":{"data":{"js_event":"leave_page","timestamp":"2015-11-22T16:18:47.088Z","uid":"l4Eys1T/rAETpysn7E/Jog==","element":"body"}}
    }, {
      "_index" : "logstash-2015.11.21",
      "_type" : "fluentd",
      "_id" : "AVEnZa5nT1yShMIEDDW8",
      "_score" : 4.0081544,
      "_source":{"data":{"js_event":"hover","timestamp":"2015-11-21T00:15:15.097Z","uid":"E/4Fdl5uETvhQeX/FZIWfQ==","element":"infographic-new-format-selector"}}
    },
...
```

Is there a way to get rid of `_index`, `_type`, `_id` and `_score`? The reason is that the query is performed on a remote server and I would like to limit the size of downloaded data.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use [response filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/common-options.html#_response_filtering) (only available since ES 1.7) by specifying what you want in the response (i.e. `filter_path=hits.hits._source`) and ES will filter it out for you:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_search?filter_path=hits.hits._source&pretty' -d '{\"_source\":[\"data.js_event\", \"data.timestamp\",\"data.uid\",\"data.element\"],\"query\":{\"match\":{\"event\":\"first_time_user_event\"}}}'
```

Comment: Exactly what I looked for (the whole afternoon!). Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry, I did not know. I just do it then.

Comment: No worries, Flavien ;) You did nothing wrong, it's just a good practice to signal to others that you were satisfied with the answer.